# How to Merge array of objects list into single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have a list of array of Objects. I need to concat the all the `options` items into one array.
Here is the sample array of objects.

```
let data = [
  {
    name: "group1",
    options: [
      {
        item: "item1",
        price: 100
      },
      {
        item: "item2",
        price: 200
      },
      {
        item: "item3",
        price: 300
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "group2",
    options: [
      {
        item: "item4",
        price: 101
      },
      {
        item: "item5",
        price: 201
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "group3",
    options: [
      {
        item: "item6",
        price: 254
      },
      {
        item: "item7",
        price: 358
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

output like:

```
let options = [
  {
    item: "item1",
    price: 100
  },
  {
    item: "item2",
    price: 200
  },
  {
    item: "item3",
    price: 300
  },
  {
    item: "item4",
    price: 101
  },
  {
    item: "item5",
    price: 201
  },
  {
    item: "item6",
    price: 254
  },
  {
    item: "item7",
    price: 358
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [**`Array.prototype.flatMap()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

> The `flatMap()` method first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) followed by a [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) of **depth** 1, but `flatMap()` is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

```
let options = data.flatMap(d => d.options);
```

```js
let data = [
  {
    name: "group1",
    options: [
      {
        item: "item1",
        price: 100
      },
      {
        item: "item2",
        price: 200
      },
      {
        item: "item3",
        price: 300
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "group2",
    options: [
      {
        item: "item4",
        price: 101
      },
      {
        item: "item5",
        price: 201
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "group3",
    options: [
      {
        item: "item6",
        price: 254
      },
      {
        item: "item7",
        price: 358
      }
    ]
  }
];


let options = data.flatMap(d => d.options);
console.log(options);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `reduce`:

```
const options = data.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item.options), [])
```